# Making Grain Gradients Only Use One Color in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, gradient

I am trying to make a gradient with a grain filter that goes from 0% opacity to black 100% opacity.  The issue I am having is in between the white color is gradually increasing in opacity, and so this shows up if I change my background color.  I am using this design for printing on multiple colors, so the gradient just needs black and nothing else.  Any ideas?[image]

Answer (score 1):

Select the object with the gradient

Open the Appearance panel (*Window > Appearance*, or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>)

Click on *Opacity*, and change the blending mode to *Multiply*

[image]

Comment: Oh wow, that feels like an obvious answer, thank you!

Comment: Now I've exported but I get the same problem.  Is there a way to export it without having the white?

Comment: @DylanCoats exported into what? the word Export really importanyt here too as export implies not all features supported.

Comment: @DylanCoats - not all file formats support blending modes. You may have to find an alternative method if you need vector output that isn't an AI file, or alternatively export in a raster format.  What format are you exporting to?  What is it going to be used for? Does it need to be vector? Note also that the Grain effects in AI are raster anyway.

Comment: I tried exporting as PNG and SVG.  It is going to be used for print on shirts so it doesn't need to be vector.  It just needs to be able to get printed on different colors of shirts.

Comment: Is it for single colour printing (in black) on a coloured t-shirt?  What kind of printing will it be?  Is it digital, or is it screen printing?  If it's digital, do you know that white is non-printing in most digital printing processes?  For example in CMYK printing, there is no white ink used in the process.

Comment: I am not too sure, I am making this for someone else.  If white is not used in printing, then my design should be fine then?  There is white that actually needs to be printed elsewhere in the design though.

Comment: @DylanCoats To get white to print on a t-shirt requires an additional separation in addition to any other colour you will be printing, and another screen. It's not regular printing. It's a specialist technique. Maybe speak to the printer. This is complex stuff.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
to remove the white color click on the white dot (1), set opacity to 0% (2)

Comment: While this will work for a normal gradient, it doesn't work if you then add a raster effect such as grain, which is what the OP is doing.